# RSA Import manual RSAParams failing with bad data error

Tags: c#, rsa

I have been at this all morning and still can't figure out what I am missing.

I am trying to perform RSA encryption using my own generated values. There are several SO post on this and several have gotten me further down the path. Some of those same post have the OP giving up and using BouncyCastle or something else while there are answers and comments saying it does work. So I'm kinda determined to learn what they know and get the .Net RSACryptoServiceProvider working.

So to that end I have a simple little sample here and I can't even get the RSAParameters to import.

I haven't posted the code used to generate and test primality or my e value. I can if needed but I don't think that is where the breakdown is as that is pretty stock code.

```
BigInteger p = BigInteger.Parse("17234...948417"); //Large Prime A
BigInteger q = BigInteger.Parse("16750...157759"); //Large Prime B
BigInteger n = BigInteger.Multiply(p, q); //Modulus
BigInteger e = BigInteger.Parse("16168...372355");

RSAParameters _rsaParams new RSAParameters();
_rsaParams.Modulus = n.ToByteArray();
_rsaParams.Exponent = e.ToByteArray();

RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.ImportParameters(_rsaParms);
```

[image: Breakpoint Inspection]

and of course the exception.

[image]

---

OK so based upon @Iridium's answer I doubled down on how I am calculating the public exponent and I was indeed doing it wrong thus coming up with too large of a public exponent. In my research for the correct way I found this very helpful site to calculate the exponent by which I was able to check myself and find my error.

> http://nmichaels.org/rsa.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I recall, the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` doesn't accept an `Exponent` in the imported parameters greater than 4 bytes (even if the number represented by the byte array would fit in a smaller field i.e. by adding leading zero bytes). Your exponent appears to be 129 bytes, which obviously exceeds this limit.

If the exponent you're using is in fact the private exponent, then the only way to get it to work with the .NET `RSACryptoServiceProvider` will be to fill in the remainder of the fields (`P`, `Q`, `DP`, `DQ`, `InverseQ`) correctly, and set the `Exponent` to the usually much smaller public exponent.

Comment: The exponent is the public key exponent.