# set public/Private keys manually in RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, rsa

I want to encrypt message in Client, then send it to another client through a server using TCP Sockets,
then decrypt it in this client

I want to use `RSACryptoServiceProvider`, but I want to set public/Private key by hand, how to do that ?

Comment: What do you mean *by hand*? If you want to set your own primes, modulus, exponent [this recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894339/rsa-import-manual-rsaparams-failing-with-bad-data-error) might be helpful.

Comment: @ArtjomB. yup I mean "set my own primes", thanks I will take a look at the link :D